# Filtrar dato específico de un Array con Foreach- PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach

Hola que tal amigos tengo el siguiente Array

```
array(1) { ["paging"]=> array(1) { 
    ["results"]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> array(2) { ["metadata"]=> array(1) { ["usuario"]=> string(9) "pedro" } ["corporation_id"]=> string(12) "bancodepedro" }
        [1]=> array(2) { ["metadata"]=> array(1) { ["usuario"]=> string(9) "juan" } ["corporation_id"]=> string(11) "bancodejuan" }
    }
}
```

y la siguiente variable:

```
$idUsuario = 'pedro';
```

Lo que necesito conseguir es, por medio de un foreach recorrer los array [0] y [1] y obtener los datos del array que contenga esa coincidencia.

Estoy intentando esto:

```
foreach ($resultado as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key is $value";
}
```

Y el resultado es:

> paging is Array results is Array

Entonces, cuando se encuentre poder mostrar algo así:

> Usuario: **pedro**

> Banco: **bancodepedro**

Agradezco sus comentarios y respuestas.

Comment: Estas recorriendo un arreglo dentro de otro arreglo, al recorrer el primero, te queda el segundo, debes obtener el dato del segundo arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de filtrar los elementos de un array en php es usando [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php).

El primer parámetro de la función es el array desde el que queremos filtrar los elementos.
El segundo, es una función de retro llamada (callback). Esta función de retro llamada recibe como parámetros el elemento actual en la iteración del array y la clave. En este ejemplo usamos solo el elemento. Fíjate que he agregado la construcción "use" para poder hacer visible la variable $idUsuario en el ámbito de la retro llamada. Si la retro llamada devuelve true el elemento sera incluido en el array resultante, si por el contrario devuelve false, será omitido.

Para tu caso el código sería este:

```
<?php

$usuarios = $results['paging']['results'];
$idUsuario = 'pedro';

$usuariosFiltrados = array_filter($usuarios, function($usuario) use ($idUsuario){
   return $usuario['usuario'] == $idUsuario;
});

// aquí usauriosFiltrados es un array que contiene un solo elemento usuario
// si hubieran más usuarios cuyo atributo 'usaurio' fuese 'pedro'
// este array resultante tendría estos elementos también
// para acceder a los datos habría que hacer algo asi
if ($usuariosFiltrados) { // el filtro produjo resultados?
   echo $usuariosFiltrados[0]['corporation_id'];
}
```

Algo interesante de la función array_filter es que podemos pasar solo el array y entonces esta devolvería solo los elementos cuyo valor se evalúa como true.

```
$aux = [
   '', // se evalúa como false
   'pedro', // se evalúa como true
   [], // se evalúa como false
];

$aux = array_filter($aux); // devolvería ['pedro']
```